# ngStorage ($localStorage) dosen't work in .then()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage). When I use my factory for jQuery's `$ajax`, I can't use `$localStorage` in `.then()` (it dosen't work).

```
$scope.updateProfile = function () {          
    updateProfileFactory.init($scope.dataProfile).then(          
        function (data)   
            if (data.status == "success") {
                $localStorage.currentUser.fullname = $scope.dataProfile.u_fullname;  
            }                 
        }        
    )
}
```

If I use `$localStorage` outside `.then()`, it work's fine, but I must put it inside.

```
$scope.updateProfile = function () {        
    $localStorage.currentUser.fullname = $scope.dataProfile.u_fullname;
    updateProfileFactory.init($scope.dataProfile).then(
        function (data) {
            if (data.status == "success") {
                // code 
            }            
        }        
    )
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Please try harder to define "it doesn't work".  Can you debug to see if the `then` function is ever even called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use Angular's `$http` library to do your AJAX stuff? Mixing jQuery and Angular proves to give unpredictable results.

I can see that you already use Angular in your application. So there really is no reason why you shouldn't go the Angular way completely. The `$http` service provides all of the functionality that jQuery's `$.ajax` provides and more.

When you use Angular functions within vanilla Javascript or jQuery functions, Angular doesn't know that these are called, as they are outside it's scope. Here you can possible use Angular's `$apply`, but that is not ideal and is hacky.

Here your problem might be that the callback function of your `$.ajax` is not aware of `$localStorage` as it is not passed in as a dependency.

Comment: I use $.ajax becouse $http "POST" have default problems with headers and data format. It is easier.

Comment: If you could post the problems you're having, we could help you out. There really is nothing that `$http` cannot do that `$.ajax` can. Headers can be set and you have complete control over the payload as well

Comment: I have project where use $.ajax is faster, easier and better way. My question isn't about $.ajax vs $http so you answears aren't helpful.

Comment: `When you use Angular functions within vanilla Javascript or jQuery functions, Angular doesn't know that these are called, as they are outside it's scope. Here you can possible use Angular's $apply, but that is not ideal and is hacky.` I have addressed your issue here.

Comment: And I was just trying to point you in the right direction, that would save you from a lot of trouble in the future, because I've been there in the past. Apologies if you felt otherwise